# Using hypothesis testing to check if a mean of a sample is bigger than the other sample.

Tags: hypothesis-testing, data-analysis, bootstrap-sampling

> Basically I am asked if people over age $35$ spend more money on average than people less or equal to age $35$ with significane level $0.05$. 
> And I have a sample of the population that I can use for my hypothesis testing.

**What I tried to do:** 
-I stated my null hypothesis that the averages are the same (no difference between them). 
-I chose my test statistic to be the difference between the averages.
Then did the bootstrap with a confidence interval of $95\%$. 
And the results I got showed that $0$ is in my confidence interval, so I accepted the null hypothesis(NOTE: I am not sure of this decision, does having zero in my confidence interval mean I can accept the null hypothesis OR does it mean I just can't reject it and it may still be true or false?). 
 and by that I answered no to the question.

**A little confusion after I have finished:**(Which probably occurred because my NOTE above). 
Looking at my visualization, I had more values in the negative side of the graph (less than $0$), when I took the difference between Average of older people minus the average of younger people (Average of how much they spend) in my bootstraps, which makes me want to say that the Average of younger people is bigger than the older people, but that won't work here because I need to have the required significance level and not just work with my intuition. 
And so I hesitated and came here to ask, is my work legitimate? did I miss something important that led to my weird conclusion? 

I would appreciate any feedback about my work, and I'm open for any nice and better ideas than mine to try them out. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One never accepts the null hypothesis, one just fails to reject it with a conclusion that you have no statistically significant evidence that the averages are different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! got a question if possible, if I decide to make a test while sampling from a distribution that has the averages are equal (instead of the bootstrap), and take the test statistic, and plot the empirical distribution of the differences of averages and say I get a $\text{P-Value}$ bigger than $0.05$, wouldn't that be enough to say that "The null hypothesis is true with a significance level of 0.05"? (or how it should be rephrased). Thanks again! and sorry if I made my question too long.

Comment: One can't flip it around and say the null is true. Sample testing is never 100% so one can never say with certainty that something is definitively true or not true. The only way one can state that is if one measures the whole population which is impractical. For any sample testing, there is always the possibility of error (Type I and Type II) so the conclusion is always either one has evidence of a difference or one doesn't have evidence of a difference.

Comment: Thanks alot! Now I get what you mean, I could only state that I can't reject the null hypothesis, because my "observed case" falls into my $95\%$ confidence interval. But now another question arrives which is: The bootstrap I did, and getting $0$ in my confidence interval is equivalent to doing models testing (making a model where the null hypothesis is true and sampling from it and getting the empirical distribution and calculating the p value) if I get a p value bigger than 0.05? in both cases I would say that I cannot reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: Even if a population has no difference in their averages (but one doesn't know that) and one gets a p value greater than 0.05, one fails to reject the null and this is a Type 2 error. That is, one failed to reject the null when one should have. Of course if one knows the averages are the same, then why perform a test? And yes, in both cases you mention, one fails to reject the null.

Comment: I'm doing it in order to answer the question stated above in the post: "Do people over age 35 spend more money on average than people less or equal to age 35? (Required significance level: 0.05)". I just realized from your answer and help about not rejecting the null hypothesis, but what I'm trying to ask, if I conducted a $95\%$ confidence interval bootstrap of difference of averages, and had zero inside of it, now I fail to reject the null hypothesis. But, would that be enough to answer the question that the averages are most likely equal, and so the answer would be "no"?